# Unexpected identifier 'express'. import call expects one or two arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, bun

I'm currently building an `express server` with `typescript` and `Bun` and just created my register route:

```
import express from "express";

const router = express.Router();
router.get('/registerUser',(_req:express.Request,res:express.Response): void => {
    res.send('Hello World');
});


module.exports = router;
```

`index.ts`:

```
SERVER.use('/pmo/api/v1/auth', require('./controllers/auth_controllers/register.controller.ts'));
```

Here is my tsconfig file:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ESNext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "composite": true,
    "strict": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "types": [
      "bun-types" // add Bun global
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried to google solutions and read forums but could not find anyone that had the same problem, all of them had a solution of putting `type="module"` in the script tag, but I do not have an HTML file, instead I have `type="module"` in my `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```js
const router = express.Router();
```

to this:

```js
export const router = express.Router();
```

and delete this:

```js
module.exports = router;
```

You cannot use `module.exports` in ES6 when you define `type="module"` in your `package.json` file. You need to use the `export` keyword instead.

Please make sure you have run `bun add express` beforehand.